# How to iterate over an observable stream of arrays in Angular 2 templates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using ng2-redux and I'm trying to show a list of phrases/words. In the following code sample, you can see that I use the `@select` decorator to grab the words/phrases and put it into the `phrases$` observable.

Going from the official ng-redux tutorial, I am able to display the array as-is by using the async pipe operator. So if the store for the phrases look like this `['one', 'two', 'three']` the output is something like this: `one, two, three`. This is what that code looks like:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { select } from 'ng2-redux';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-typing',
  template: `
    <h2>List of Phrases</h2>
    <div>{{ phrases$ | async }}</div>
  `,
})
export class TypingComponent implements OnInit {

  @select('phrase') phrases$: Observable<number>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

But my goal is not to display the words in a single line. I would like to display the words with `*ngFor` so I could do more complex styling on them. So, instead of `{{ phrases$ | async }}`, maybe something like this:

```js
<div *ngFor="let phrase in phrases$">
  <div>{{phrase}}</div>
<div>
```

But this doesn't work, because `phrases$` is an observable and not an array. How can I change what I have above so that I can iterate over the array itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `phrases$` emits an array, the type seems to be incorrect. Should it not be:

```
@select('phrase') phrases$: Observable<number[]>;
```

If it does emit an array, you can use the `async` pipe like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let phrase in phrases$ | async">
  <div>{{phrase}}</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Regarding the type, you'er right, I made a mistake there. But thanks for the answer regarding the async pipe. Just what I was looking for!